# Taylor series does not match

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have the following

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Bigg(k\int_{a}^b e^{-tx^{(-c)}}dx\Bigg)^n}{n!} \text{}dt
$$

To explain my problem, I would like you to check what happens to the sum when $t \rightarrow \infty$. In particular, the term $e^{-tx^{(-c)}}$ tends to $0$ and so it does the integral over $dx$ and the sum over $n$.

As far as $\bigg|k\int_{a}^b e^{-tx^{(-c)}}dx\bigg|<1$, I should be able to write the entire above equation as

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\exp\Bigg(k\int_{a}^b e^{-tx^{(-c)}}dx\Bigg) \text{}dt
$$

We try again the experimentation for $t \rightarrow \infty$ but in this case the integral over $dt$ tends to one since $e^{-tx^{(-c)}} \rightarrow 0 $ (exactly as above), and so I will have an infinite sum over $\exp(0)=1$ which diverges.

Why does it happen? What did I miss? ($k,a,b,c$ are all positive real numbers)

Thanks a lot

Comment: In the series form, the term for $n = 0$ is $1$, regardless of what $k,t,c,a,b$ are.

Comment: For each $t$ the summation IS $F(t)=\exp (k\int_a^be^{tx^{-c}}dx)$. The entire expression is then $\int_0^{\infty}F(t)dt$ which could be just about anything, depending on the nature of the function $F(t).$